# A function that maps $R^m \to R^n$ where, $m<n$ is called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I forgot the name of the type of functions that map a smaller space to a larger one, in this case $$g(x_1,...,x_m)=(x_1,...,x_m,0,0,0,...,x_n=0)$$ What is this type of function called?

Comment: There's no _general_ name for functions of this type, but if you assume $g$ is continuously differentiable and $Dg$ has rank $m$ at each point, then $g$ is an _immersion_; if $g$ is in addition a homeomorphism to its image (in the subspace topology), then $g$ is an _embedding_.

Answer (score 3):

Ideas:

- Injection
- Inclusion
- Monomorphism
- Immersion
- Section
- Embedding

(Thanks lisyarus for monomorphism and injection and embedding!)

Comment: I'd add *monomorphism* and *immersion*.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add them to the list

Comment: Oh, and *embedding*! :)

Answer (score 1):

Both "injection map" and "inclusion map" are very special cases.  In particular, an "inclusion map" treats $R^m$ as a subspace of $R^n$ and maps $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_m)$ to $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_m, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0)$ while "injection map" is a general **type** of map, not necessarily $R^m$ to $R^n$.